# how to access api with Angularjs service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am trying to register user thorugh restful api in AngularJs..i tried below code but did not get any response.

HTML

```
    <div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
Email: <input ng-model="email" type="text"/>
Password: <input ng-model="password" type="text"/>
<button ng-click ="register()" type="button">Submit</button>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
    app.controller('LoginCtrl', [
      '$scope','AuthService',
      function($scope, AuthService) {
         $scope.register = function(){
            AuthService.createUser($scope.email, $scope.password);
         }
      }]
   );
```

SERVICE

```
    app.service('AuthService', [
      '$http',
      function($http) {
         this.createUser = function(email, password) {
            $http.post("https://api-e1.authrocket.com/v1/users",
                headers: {
                    'X-Authrocket-Account': 'org_0v8CbVRzgfKQobpZSgde6h',
                    'X-Authrocket-Api-Key': 'key_XznPZ8nhhA7l1KH39wPLHRadqoJ2gdfk8sO6hbE1Q2d'
                },
                user: {
                    username: 'abc',
                    user_type: 'human'
                });
         }
      }]
   );
```

Comment: have you checked the network tab to see if the request and response are successful?

Comment: Hope the api account and key arent private

Comment: shouldn't the hardcoded values be changed to argument params?

Comment: I'm also sceptic about your RESTFull api... Are you sure that the api works? And why do you have hardcoded values in username/human?

Comment: Thanks i got it corrected..